# My numeric text-box at kendo grid filter is showing infinity values

Tags: kendo-grid

I have kendo grid in my application.And in my grid filterable is true.In grid one row has numeric text-box in filter,when we click on spinners it is showing infinity values.So I want to give some limit for numeric text-boxes in filter.How to give some limit for numeric text boxes in grid filter.?
My grid code is

```
                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type           : "odata",
            transport      : {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema         : {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        OrderID  : { type: "number" },
                        Freight  : { type: "number" },
                        ShipName : { type: "string" },
                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                        ShipCity : { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize       : 10
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable  : true,
        pageable  : true,
        columns   : [
            {
                field     : "OrderID",
                filterable: false
            },
            "Freight",
            {
                field : "OrderDate",
                title : "Order Date",
                width : 100,
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
            },
            {
                field: "ShipName",
                title: "Ship Name",
                width: 200
            },
            {
                field: "ShipCity",
                title: "Ship City"
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: I am trying like this but no result                                  filterable: 
                                  { 
                                      min:0,max:50
                                    extra: false, 
                                    operators: { 
                                         number: {
                                          eq: "Is Equal To",
                                          neq: "Is Not Equal To"
                                            
                    }}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try this

```
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
  var numeric = e.container.find("[data-role=numerictextbox]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
  if (numeric) {
    numeric.min(0);
  }
}
```